# Setting background colour of ListView header fill space

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am theming my WinForms controls and trying to create a dark version of the ListView control. I would like to change the background colour of the headers so they are all black. Each heading can be painted in black, but what is left is some whitespace where there are no headings.

How do I paint this space as I do not see a property for it?

I have created a simple WinForms application to demonstrate my problem.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listView1.OwnerDraw = true;
        listView1.BackColor = Color.Black;
        listView1.DrawColumnHeader += (sender, args) =>
        {
            args.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, args.Bounds);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(args.Graphics, args.Header.Text, args.Font, args.Bounds, Color.White);
        };
        listView1.DrawItem += (sender, args) => args.DrawDefault = true;
        listView1.DrawSubItem += (sender, args) => args.DrawDefault = true;
    }
}
```

[image: app]

Comment: tough one. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433292/drawing-outside-of-column-area-in-listview-column-header?rq=1)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. No idea why I didn't find this after searching for the past hour.

Comment: _c# winforms  ListView draw header empty space_